# A way to .split() case insensitive without using regexp

Tags: javascript

I have a function that search for key-words and applies it a wrapper with a class to highlight them. I'm using a `split()-join()` pattern, but it's a case sensitive way and need to make it insensitive. I don't know if this is possible to achieve without regexp. This is the piece of code anyway:

`var holder = data_title_string.split(" " + key_words.keys[j] + " ").join("<span style='color:green;'> " + key_words.keys[j] + " </span>");`

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

- data_title_string could be " Adidas opens the market with an
  underscore of 10%".
- key_words.keys is "adidas".

Then the title won't be highlighted because the keyword doesn't match the capitalization of "Adidas". It only will highlight the titles where adidas is on lower case. That happen with all the possible scenarios.

Comment: do you have some data, before and after?

Comment: Please add input data (more than 1 sample) + desired result for each.

Comment: if you can give us some test cases, we can take a look.  Though, you can likely just `toLowerCase()` (sp) and then do a comparison on lowercases without using a regex

Comment: If you don't want to use `toLowerCase`, you have to use regex. But you can still use split with regex https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: This will hardly be possible without regex. You would need to either upper- or lowercase everything, before you perform your “search” - but then you won’t be able to assemble the parts back together in their original case, at least not in any easy way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the constructor of `RegExp` and pass as a second param the letter/flag `i` for insensitive look-up.

```js
let target = "ele",
    regex = new RegExp(target, "i"),
    holder = "Ele from stackoverflow".split(regex).join("<span style='color:green;'> " + target + " </span>");

console.log(holder);
```

Comment: I can't use regexp.